# jquery - show hidden div when click value radio button

Tags: jquery

Hy guys 
I would show my div when click on value radio button.
My Html:

```
 <form id="risp">
            <input id="ris1" type="radio" name="ris" value="err1">                     <label class="answer">0</label>
            <input id="ris2" type="radio" name="ris" value="err1">                      <label class="answer"> 2</label>
            <input id="ris3" type="radio" name="ris" value="correct1">                    <label class="answer">5</label>
        </form>

<div id="correct">
        <p>answer correct</p>
    </div>
```

So I try this function:

```
$("#ris3").click(function () {
                        $("correct").show();
```

but don't function!!Why??
Thanx

Comment: Don't forget to close your .click() function as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's because:

```
$('correct')
```

Should be:

```
$('#correct')
```

The problem is that your selector is wrong. Keep in mind a selector like `$('correct')` would be looking for a `<correct>` element which does not exist. For IDs, you have to use `#` and `.` for classes either one before the actual value. You can find more information on jQuery selectors here: **http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/**

**<kbd>[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/4u6TA/)</kbd>**

Note: as Stuart Kershaw mentioned on the comment below, remember to close your click function, otherwise it won't work...